# mongodb sharding error

Tags: mongodb

Does anyone can help?
Mongdb sharding in v4.2 raise error:

```
2023-05-14T00:08:14.765+0000 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Request 18983 timed out, deadline was 2023-05-14T00:08:14.756+0000, op was RemoteCommand 18983 -- target:[172.41.29.18:27001] db:config expDate:2023-05-14T00:08:14.756+0000 cmd:{ find: \"collections\", filter: { _id: /^config\\./ }, readConcern: { level: \"majority\", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp(1683949632, 1), t: 140 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }",
    "code" : 202,
    "codeName" : "NetworkInterfaceExceededTimeLimit",
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684022890, 2),
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1684022890, 2),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"OeUbGoFBKr7Gw6aYSpg6dnYrCnM="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("7175349188501176681")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.